# Create additional rows in select statement result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, rows

I am creating a fairly complex SELECT query with joins across multiple tables and views. The primary table is joined with several secondary tables. The result set of rows needs to be further split up based on approximately 25 CASE statement conditions for two scenarios:

1. Where one column is checked for a particular value based on which a new row has to be created with some unique values for a few columns;
2. Where two columns using an AND condition have to be checked in order to create a new row

Here is an example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col25, col26, col27, col48
FROM T1
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table2.col1 = T1.col1
INNER JOIN Table3 on Table3.col2 = T1.col1
```

Col25 is being compared with a column (Table2.ColA) from an INNER JOIN and this is where my CASE conditions are required, approximately 25 of them:

```
CASE WHEN Table2.ColA = 'W-%' THEN Col25 = 'WATER'
```

and I also need to insert one or more additional rows where

```
Col25 = 'REL', 
Col26 = 5000,
Col27 = 'M'
```

Basically what the CASE expression is supposed to do is replace a value for the resulting row from my SELECT statement, and also insert one or more rows with different values for Col25, Col26, Col27 while keeping other column values the same as those returned by the SELECT statement.

I understand that this might involve more than just my select statements and could require traversing a cursor containing the result of my primary query in order to create the news rows. Is this the only route available to me? Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you provided a simplified version of your problem in the form of some sample data.  Sample data being table creation and value insert sql statements.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: 1. What does it mean "some unique values for a few columns"? Maybe some example. 2. Do you mean that 2 columns must have specific values in order to trigger condition? . Cursors are generally the last choice, and should only be used when all other options are worse. You need to provide us with some prototype/example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added a code example. Not sure if this sufficient.

Comment: Just put the case statement in your select clause?  I'm confused what isn't working, what you've tried to do, and what you want to accomplish.  `SELECT Col24, CASE WHEN Table2.ColA = 'W-%' THEN 'WATER' as Col25 , 5000 as Col26, 'M' as Col27, Table3.col29 ... whatever you want`

Comment: First, I think you misunderstand what `case` does. Are the new rows going to be modified copies?

Comment: @avery_larry My problem is that for each CASE statement that meets a condition, not only do I need to replace a string in the returned row (let's call ir Row-100) with 'XXX', I also need to insert an additional new row where some columns are assigned new values based on the CASE and copy all other values from Row-100.

Comment: @shawnt00 The new rows are going to be modified copies of the returned row. Please see my response to the previous comment.

Comment: Well, I think you'll have to look at perhaps IF statements with different logic.  Or perhaps union all multiple subsets together.  I think we'll need representative existing data and expected different outputs for different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

```
with q as ( -- your query
    select ...
)
select * from q
union all
select ... from q
where <conditions requiring a copy>
```

Option 2

```
inner join (values ('org'), ('new')) copy(flag) on flag = 'org' or
    flag = 'new' and 1 = case
        when col25 = 'A' then 1
        when col25 = 'B' and col26 = 'X' then 1
        ...
    end
```

For output columns you'd need similar `cases` to distinguish between original row and new row.

Comment: I'm going to try the first method. Would I require multiple "union all" statements and queries if I have several rows to copy?

Comment: You need multiple unions if you need *more than one* copy. But for copying different rows, no.